# Large overdetermined system of quadratic equations

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

Could anyone help to solve the system of 81 quadratic equations with 27 variables? The system has solutions. Constraint: 
$\sum_{i=0}^{26} x^2_i=1$

$-x_1 x_3-x_2 x_6+x_1 x_9+x_2 x_{18}=0$

$-x_1 x_4-x_2 x_7+x_1 x_{10}+x_2 x_{19}=0$

$-x_1 x_5-x_2 x_8+x_1 x_{11}+x_2 x_{20}=0$

$-x_3 x_4-x_5 x_6+x_1 x_{12}+x_2 x_{21}=0$

$-x_1 x_3+x_0 x_4-x_4^2-x_5 x_7+x_1 x_{13}+x_2 x_{22}=0$

$-x_2 x_3+x_0 x_5-x_4 x_5-x_5 x_8+x_1 x_{14}+x_2 x_{23}=0$

$-x_3 x_7-x_6 x_8+x_1 x_{15}+x_2 x_{24}=0$

$-x_1 x_6+x_0 x_7-x_4 x_7-x_7 x_8+x_1 x_{16}+x_2 x_{25}=0$

$-x_2 x_6-x_5 x_7+x_0 x_8-x_8^2+x_1 x_{17}+x_2 x_{26}=0$

$x_0 x_3-x_0 x_9+x_4 x_9-x_3 x_{10}-x_6 x_{11}+x_5 x_{18}=0$

$x_1 x_3-x_1 x_9-x_7 x_{11}+x_5 x_{19}=0$

$x_2 x_3-x_2 x_9-x_5 x_{10}+x_4 x_{11}-x_8 x_{11}+x_5 x_{20}=0$

$x_3^2-x_0 x_{12}+x_4 x_{12}-x_3 x_{13}-x_6 x_{14}+x_5 x_{21}=0$

$x_3 x_4-x_1 x_{12}-x_7 x_{14}+x_5 x_{22}=0$

$x_3 x_5-x_2 x_{12}-x_5 x_{13}+x_4 x_{14}-x_8 x_{14}+x_5 x_{23}=0$

$x_3 x_6-x_0 x_{15}+x_4 x_{15}-x_3 x_{16}-x_6 x_{17}+x_5 x_{24}=0$

$x_3 x_7-x_1 x_{15}-x_7 x_{17}+x_5 x_{25}=0$

$x_3 x_8-x_2 x_{15}-x_5 x_{16}+x_4 x_{17}-x_8 x_{17}+x_5 x_{26}=0$

$x_0 x_6+x_7 x_9-x_0 x_{18}+x_8 x_{18}-x_3 x_{19}-x_6 x_{20}=0$

$x_1 x_6+x_7 x_{10}-x_1 x_{18}-x_4 x_{19}+x_8 x_{19}-x_7 x_{20}=0$

$x_2 x_6+x_7 x_{11}-x_2 x_{18}-x_5 x_{19}=0$

$x_3 x_6+x_7 x_{12}-x_0 x_{21}+x_8 x_{21}-x_3 x_{22}-x_6 x_{23}=0$

$x_4 x_6+x_7 x_{13}-x_1 x_{21}-x_4 x_{22}+x_8 x_{22}-x_7 x_{23}=0$

$x_5 x_6+x_7 x_{14}-x_2 x_{21}-x_5 x_{22}=0$

$x_6^2+x_7 x_{15}-x_0 x_{24}+x_8 x_{24}-x_3 x_{25}-x_6 x_{26}=0$

$x_6 x_7+x_7 x_{16}-x_1 x_{24}-x_4 x_{25}+x_8 x_{25}-x_7 x_{26}=0$

$x_6 x_8+x_7 x_{17}-x_2 x_{24}-x_5 x_{25}=0$

$x_9 x_{10}-x_1 x_{12}-x_2 x_{15}+x_{11} x_{18}=0$

$x_1 x_9-x_0 x_{10}+x_{10}^2-x_1 x_{13}-x_2 x_{16}+x_{11} x_{19}=0$

$x_2 x_9-x_0 x_{11}+x_{10} x_{11}-x_1 x_{14}-x_2 x_{17}+x_{11} x_{20}=0$

$-x_4 x_{12}+x_{10} x_{12}-x_5 x_{15}+x_{11} x_{21}=0$

$x_4 x_9-x_3 x_{10}-x_4 x_{13}+x_{10} x_{13}-x_5 x_{16}+x_{11} x_{22}=0$

$x_5 x_9-x_3 x_{11}-x_4 x_{14}+x_{10} x_{14}-x_5 x_{17}+x_{11} x_{23}=0$

$-x_7 x_{12}-x_8 x_{15}+x_{10} x_{15}+x_{11} x_{24}=0$

$x_7 x_9-x_6 x_{10}-x_7 x_{13}-x_8 x_{16}+x_{10} x_{16}+x_{11} x_{25}=0$

$x_8 x_9-x_6 x_{11}-x_7 x_{14}-x_8 x_{17}+x_{10} x_{17}+x_{11} x_{26}=0$

$-x_9^2+x_0 x_{12}-x_{10} x_{12}+x_9 x_{13}-x_{11} x_{15}+x_{14} x_{18}=0$

$-x_9 x_{10}+x_1 x_{12}-x_{11} x_{16}+x_{14} x_{19}=0$

$-x_9 x_{11}+x_2 x_{12}+x_{11} x_{13}-x_{10} x_{14}-x_{11} x_{17}+x_{14} x_{20}=0$

$x_3 x_{12}-x_9 x_{12}-x_{14} x_{15}+x_{14} x_{21}=0$

$x_4 x_{12}-x_{10} x_{12}-x_{14} x_{16}+x_{14} x_{22}=0$

$x_5 x_{12}-x_{11} x_{12}-x_{14} x_{17}+x_{14} x_{23}=0$

$x_6 x_{12}-x_9 x_{15}+x_{13} x_{15}-x_{12} x_{16}-x_{15} x_{17}+x_{14} x_{24}=0$

$x_7 x_{12}-x_{10} x_{15}-x_{16} x_{17}+x_{14} x_{25}=0$

$x_8 x_{12}-x_{11} x_{15}-x_{14} x_{16}+x_{13} x_{17}-x_{17}^2+x_{14} x_{26}=0$

$x_0 x_{15}+x_9 x_{16}-x_9 x_{18}+x_{17} x_{18}-x_{12} x_{19}-x_{15} x_{20}=0$

$x_1 x_{15}+x_{10} x_{16}-x_{10} x_{18}-x_{13} x_{19}+x_{17} x_{19}-x_{16} x_{20}=0$

$x_2 x_{15}+x_{11} x_{16}-x_{11} x_{18}-x_{14} x_{19}=0$

$x_3 x_{15}+x_{12} x_{16}-x_9 x_{21}+x_{17} x_{21}-x_{12} x_{22}-x_{15} x_{23}=0$

$x_4 x_{15}+x_{13} x_{16}-x_{10} x_{21}-x_{13} x_{22}+x_{17} x_{22}-x_{16} x_{23}=0$

$x_5 x_{15}+x_{14} x_{16}-x_{11} x_{21}-x_{14} x_{22}=0$

$x_6 x_{15}+x_{15} x_{16}-x_9 x_{24}+x_{17} x_{24}-x_{12} x_{25}-x_{15} x_{26}=0$

$x_7 x_{15}+x_{16}^2-x_{10} x_{24}-x_{13} x_{25}+x_{17} x_{25}-x_{16} x_{26}=0$

$x_8 x_{15}+x_{16} x_{17}-x_{11} x_{24}-x_{14} x_{25}=0$

$x_9 x_{19}+x_{18} x_{20}-x_1 x_{21}-x_2 x_{24}=0$

$x_1 x_{18}-x_0 x_{19}+x_{10} x_{19}+x_{19} x_{20}-x_1 x_{22}-x_2 x_{25}=0$

$x_2 x_{18}+x_{11} x_{19}-x_0 x_{20}+x_{20}^2-x_1 x_{23}-x_2 x_{26}=0$

$x_{12} x_{19}-x_4 x_{21}+x_{20} x_{21}-x_5 x_{24}=0$

$x_4 x_{18}-x_3 x_{19}+x_{13} x_{19}-x_4 x_{22}+x_{20} x_{22}-x_5 x_{25}=0$

$x_5 x_{18}+x_{14} x_{19}-x_3 x_{20}-x_4 x_{23}+x_{20} x_{23}-x_5 x_{26}=0$

$x_{15} x_{19}-x_7 x_{21}-x_8 x_{24}+x_{20} x_{24}=0$

$x_7 x_{18}-x_6 x_{19}+x_{16} x_{19}-x_7 x_{22}-x_8 x_{25}+x_{20} x_{25}=0$

$x_8 x_{18}+x_{17} x_{19}-x_6 x_{20}-x_7 x_{23}-x_8 x_{26}+x_{20} x_{26}=0$

$-x_9 x_{18}+x_0 x_{21}-x_{10} x_{21}+x_9 x_{22}+x_{18} x_{23}-x_{11} x_{24}=0$

$-x_9 x_{19}+x_1 x_{21}+x_{19} x_{23}-x_{11} x_{25}=0$

$-x_9 x_{20}+x_2 x_{21}+x_{11} x_{22}-x_{10} x_{23}+x_{20} x_{23}-x_{11} x_{26}=0$

$-x_{12} x_{18}+x_3 x_{21}-x_{13} x_{21}+x_{12} x_{22}+x_{21} x_{23}-x_{14} x_{24}=0$

$-x_{12} x_{19}+x_4 x_{21}+x_{22} x_{23}-x_{14} x_{25}=0$

$-x_{12} x_{20}+x_5 x_{21}+x_{14} x_{22}-x_{13} x_{23}+x_{23}^2-x_{14} x_{26}=0$

$-x_{15} x_{18}+x_6 x_{21}-x_{16} x_{21}+x_{15} x_{22}-x_{17} x_{24}+x_{23} x_{24}=0$

$-x_{15} x_{19}+x_7 x_{21}-x_{17} x_{25}+x_{23} x_{25}=0$

$-x_{15} x_{20}+x_8 x_{21}+x_{17} x_{22}-x_{16} x_{23}-x_{17} x_{26}+x_{23} x_{26}=0$

$-x_{18}^2-x_{19} x_{21}+x_0 x_{24}-x_{20} x_{24}+x_9 x_{25}+x_{18} x_{26}=0$

$-x_{18} x_{19}-x_{19} x_{22}+x_1 x_{24}+x_{10} x_{25}-x_{20} x_{25}+x_{19} x_{26}=0$

$-x_{18} x_{20}-x_{19} x_{23}+x_2 x_{24}+x_{11} x_{25}=0$

$-x_{18} x_{21}-x_{21} x_{22}+x_3 x_{24}-x_{23} x_{24}+x_{12} x_{25}+x_{21} x_{26}=0$

$-x_{19} x_{21}-x_{22}^2+x_4 x_{24}+x_{13} x_{25}-x_{23} x_{25}+x_{22} x_{26}=0$

$-x_{20} x_{21}-x_{22} x_{23}+x_5 x_{24}+x_{14} x_{25}=0$

$x_6 x_{24}-x_{18} x_{24}+x_{15} x_{25}-x_{21} x_{25}=0$

$x_7 x_{24}-x_{19} x_{24}+x_{16} x_{25}-x_{22} x_{25}=0$

$x_8 x_{24}-x_{20} x_{24}+x_{17} x_{25}-x_{23} x_{25}=0$

```
Do[{i, j, k} = {0, 0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]]}; 
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 0, 2, 1}]
Do[{i, j, k} = {0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], 
   IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]]}; 
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 3, 8, 1}]
Do[{i, j, k} = {IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]], 
   IntegerDigits[l, 3][[3]]}; 
 Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 9, 26, 1}]

Do[lam = j 3^3 + k 3^2 + n 3 + s; 
 Subscript[eq, lam] = 
  Sum[Co[j, k, m]*Co[m, n, s] - Co[k, n, m]*Co[j, m, s], {m, 0, 2, 
    1}], {j, 0, 2, 1}, {k, 0, 2, 1}, {n, 0, 2, 1}, {s, 0, 2, 1}]

Solve[
 Subscript[eq, 1] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 2] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 3] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 4] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 5] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 6] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 7] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 8] == 0 && 
 Subscript[eq, 9] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 10] == 0 &&
  Subscript[eq, 11] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 12] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 13] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 14] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 15] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 16] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 17] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 18] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 19] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 20] == 0 &&
  Subscript[eq, 21] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 22] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 23] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 24] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 25] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 26] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 27] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 28] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 29] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 30] == 0 &&
  Subscript[eq, 31] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 32] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 33] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 34] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 35] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 36] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 37] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 38] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 39] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 40] == 0 &&
  Subscript[eq, 41] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 42] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 43] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 44] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 45] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 46] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 47] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 48] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 49] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 50] == 0 &&
  Subscript[eq, 51] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 52] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 53] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 54] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 55] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 56] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 57] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 58] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 59] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 60] == 0 &&
  Subscript[eq, 61] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 62] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 63] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 64] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 65] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 66] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 67] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 68] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 69] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 70] == 0 &&
  Subscript[eq, 71] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 72] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 73] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 74] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 75] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 76] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 77] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 78] == 0 && 
  Subscript[eq, 79] == 0 && Subscript[eq, 80] == 0 &&
  Subscript[eq, 0] == 0
 , {Subscript[x, 0], Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 
  3], Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5], Subscript[x, 6], Subscript[x, 
  7], Subscript[x, 8], Subscript[x, 9], Subscript[x, 10], Subscript[x,
   11], Subscript[x, 12], Subscript[x, 13], Subscript[x, 14], 
  Subscript[x, 15], Subscript[x, 16], Subscript[x, 17], Subscript[x, 
  18], Subscript[x, 19], Subscript[x, 20], Subscript[x, 21], 
  Subscript[x, 22], Subscript[x, 23], Subscript[x, 24], Subscript[x, 
     25], Subscript[x, 26]}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Maybe `FindMinimum[#.#&[eqns /. Equal -> Subtract], Variables[eqns /. Equal -> Subtract]]`...

Comment: I don't know if I could solve it given input (probably not would be my guess). I do know I cannot solve it without cut-and-pastable input.

Comment: How do you know that this system of equations has a solution.  Also, are the variables Real?  By the way, your code is missing the normalization equation. (sum of squares equals 1).

Comment: @ bbgodfrey, The variables are real. The condition is optional. It is designed in order to exclude zero solution and solutions that are constant times another solution. It is related to "a classification of all algebra structures on a 3-dimensional vector space", so it has solutions ( see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3010718/associativity-equation-for-structure-constants)

Answer (score 5):

Symbolic solutions can be obtained as follows.

**Compact derivation of equations**

To begin, it is convenient to simplify the code in the question, which is equivalent to

```
Set @@@ Table[{Co @@ IntegerDigits[l, 3, 3], x[l]}, {l, 0, 26}];
eqs = Set @@@ Table[{j, k, n, s} = IntegerDigits[lam, 3, 4]; {eq[lam], 
  Sum[Co[j, k, m]*Co[m, n, s] - Co[k, n, m]*Co[j, m, s], {m, 0, 2}]}, {lam, 0, 80}];
norm = Sum[x[l]^2, {l, 0, 26}];
```

The natural next step is to try to `Solve` the `81` equations directly for the `27` variables with

```
Solve[Thread[eqs == 0], Table[x[l], {l, 0, 26}]]
```

However, `Solve` eventually devoured the entire `16 GB` memory of my computer and had to be terminated.  (It is convenient to ignore the normalization constraint, `norm`, when attempting to derive a symbolic solution.  See one of the OP's comments above.)

**Using a Numerical Solution for Guidance**

[Bill](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/18890/bill) derived an accurate numerical solution earlier.  Using the formulation in my answer, a numerical result is obtained by

```
sol = NMinimize[Total[Map[Norm, Join[eqs, {norm - 1}]]], 
    Table[x[l], {l, 0, 26}], WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

Although the result is a bit long to reproduce here, three points should be made.  First, `norm - 1` must be included in the numerical calculation to avoid the trivial solution. Second, my solution differs substantially from Bill's, which is not surprising, because the equations have many solutions.  (See a comment above by the OP.)  Third, several pairs of `x[_]` have the same values to high precision.  The pairs can be identified and linked with `Rule` by

```
GatherBy[Last[sol], Round[Last[#], 10^-6] &];
sim = Cases[%, {Rule[z1_, _], Rule[z2_, _]} -> Rule[z2, z1]]
(* {x[9] -> x[3], x[10] -> x[4], x[11] -> x[5], x[18] -> x[6], x[19] -> x[7], 
    x[20] -> x[8], x[21] -> x[15], x[22] -> x[16], x[23] -> x[17]} *)
```

Several other numerical solutions can be obtain by, for instance, varying `WorkingPrecision` slightly or by reordering the equations in `Join[eqs, {norm - 1}]`.  All have the identical relationships among `x[_]`, suggesting that they represent true identities.  Applying these rules reduces the number of independent variables and equations by a third each.

```
varsim = Union[Table[x[l], {l, 0, 26}] /. sim];
Length@varsim
(* 18 *)

eqssim = DeleteCases[eqs /. sim, 0];
Length@eqssim
(* 54 *)
```

(`27` of the `eqs` equations vanish identically and can be eliminated.)  Unfortunately, `Solve` cannot handle this reduced set of equations either, crashing after about three hours on my computer.

**General Solution**

The OP in a comment above described a similar but simpler problem involving eight variables and sixteen equations.  Solving that problem is straightforward, resulting in expressions for four of the variables in terms of the other four (or five in terms of three, if `norm == 1` is included in the computation.)  With this as an example, I found that I could `Solve` `eqssim` for the last nine elements of `varsim` in terms of the first nine elements.

```
Solve[Thread[eqssim == 0], varsim[[10 ;; 18]]] // Simplify
```

which yields a general solution of rational expressions for the last nine elements of `varsim` in about a minute.  In other words, nine of the variables can be specified arbitrarily, and from them the other nine can be calculated (ten in terms of eight, if `norm == 1` is included).  Although the expressions are too long to be reproduced here, an example is

```
x[12] -> (x[1] x[5] (x[3] x[4] + x[5] x[6]) - x[2] (x[4] x[5] x[6] + x[3] (x[4]^2 + 
    x[5] x[7] - x[4] x[8])))/(x[1]^2 x[5] - x[2]^2 x[7] + x[1] x[2] (-x[4] + x[8]))
```

Attempting to specify more than half of the variables arbitrarily does not, in general, satisfy `eqssim`, and `Solve` returns an empty list as the solution.

**Special Solutions**

Clearly, the expression above for `x[12]` of the general solution is invalid for `{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0}`, in which case many special solutions can be obtained by

```
n1 = 1; n2 = 2; 
eqs1 = eqs /. {x[n1] -> 0, x[n2] -> 0}; norm1 = norm /. {x[n1] -> 0, x[n2] -> 0};
sol1 = NMinimize[Total[Map[Norm, Join[{norm1 - 1}, eqs1]]], 
    Delete[Table[x[l], {l, 0, 26}], {{n1 + 1}, {n2 + 1}}], WorkingPrecision -> 30];
GatherBy[Last[sol1], Round[Last[#], 10^-6] &];
Cases[%, {Rule[z1_, _], Rule[z2_, _]} -> Rule[z2, z1]];
Cases[sol1, (Rule[z1_, z2_] /; Abs[z2] < 10^-6) -> Rule[z1, 0], 2];
sim1 = Flatten[{{x[n1] -> 0, x[n2] -> 0}, %, %%}]
(* {x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[4] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, x[7] -> 0, x[8] -> 0, 
    x[10] -> 0, x[11] -> 0, x[19] -> 0, x[20] -> 0, x[9] -> x[3], 
    x[18] -> x[6], x[21] -> x[15], x[22] -> x[16], x[23] -> x[17]} *)
```

Applying these rules greatly reduces`eqs` and the number of remaining variables

```
varsim1 = DeleteCases[Union[Table[x[l], {l, 0, 26}] /. sim1], 0]
Length@varsim1
(* 12 *)

eqssim1 = DeleteCases[eqs /. sim1, 0]; 
Length@eqssim1
(* 20 *)

Solve[Thread[eqssim1 == 0], varsim1] // Simplify
```

The resulting list of `67` solutions is quite lengthy and cannot be reproduced here.  As a sample, the first special solution is

```
{x[0] -> (x[3] (x[6] - x[16]) - x[6] x[17])/x[15], 
 x[13] -> x[3] + (x[12] (-x[6] + x[16]))/x[15] + 
     (x[6] (-x[14] + (x[12] x[17])/x[15]))/x[3], 
 x[24] -> (x[6] x[14] x[15] - x[6] x[12] x[17] + x[3] x[15] x[17])/(x[3] x[14]), 
 x[25] -> (x[16] x[17])/x[14], 
 x[26] -> (1/(x[3] x[14] x[15]))(-x[3]^2 x[15] x[17] + x[6] x[17] 
     (x[14] x[15] - x[12] x[17]) + x[3] (x[14] x[15] x[16] + x[17] 
     (x[6] x[12] - x[12] x[16] + x[15] x[17])))}
```

Of course, several of these solutions are invalid for other `x[_] == 0`.  In the case of `x[3] == 0`, the same process as applied earlier in this section yields `91` special solutions, all but ten of which are distinct from those above.  The total number of special solutions must be very large indeed.

Answer (score 4):

```
NMinimize[Total[Map[Norm,{
  x0^2+x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+x4^2+x5^2+x6^2+x7^2+x8^2+x9^2+
  x10^2+x11^2+x12^2+x13^2+x14^2+x15^2+x16^2+x17^2+x18^2+x19^2+
  x20^2+x21^2+x22^2+x23^2+x24^2+x25^2+x26^2-1,
  -x1*x3-x2*x6+x1*x9+x2*x18,
  -x1*x4-x2*x7+x1*x10+x2*x19,
  -x1*x5-x2*x8+x1*x11+x2*x20,
  -x3*x4-x5*x6+x1*x12+x2*x21,
  -x1*x3+x0*x4-x4^2-x5*x7+x1*x13+x2*x22,
  -x2*x3+x0*x5-x4*x5-x5*x8+x1*x14+x2*x23,
  -x3*x7-x6*x8+x1*x15+x2*x24,
  -x1*x6+x0*x7-x4*x7-x7*x8+x1*x16+x2*x25,
  -x2*x6-x5*x7+x0*x8-x8^2+x1*x17+x2*x26,
  x0*x3-x0*x9+x4*x9-x3*x10-x6*x11+x5*x18,
  x1*x3-x1*x9-x7*x11+x5*x19,
  x2*x3-x2*x9-x5*x10+x4*x11-x8*x11+x5*x20,
  x3^2-x0*x12+x4*x12-x3*x13-x6*x14+x5*x21,
  x3*x4-x1*x12-x7*x14+x5*x22,
  x3*x5-x2*x12-x5*x13+x4*x14-x8*x14+x5*x23,
  x3*x6-x0*x15+x4*x15-x3*x16-x6*x17+x5*x24,
  x3*x7-x1*x15-x7*x17+x5*x25,
  x3*x8-x2*x15-x5*x16+x4*x17-x8*x17+x5*x26,
  x0*x6+x7*x9-x0*x18+x8*x18-x3*x19-x6*x20,
  x1*x6+x7*x10-x1*x18-x4*x19+x8*x19-x7*x20,
  x2*x6+x7*x11-x2*x18-x5*x19,
  x3*x6+x7*x12-x0*x21+x8*x21-x3*x22-x6*x23,
  x4*x6+x7*x13-x1*x21-x4*x22+x8*x22-x7*x23,
  x5*x6+x7*x14-x2*x21-x5*x22,
  x6^2+x7*x15-x0*x24+x8*x24-x3*x25-x6*x26,
  x6*x7+x7*x16-x1*x24-x4*x25+x8*x25-x7*x26,
  x6*x8+x7*x17-x2*x24-x5*x25,
  x9*x10-x1*x12-x2*x15+x11*x18,
  x1*x9-x0*x10+x10^2-x1*x13-x2*x16+x11*x19,
  x2*x9-x0*x11+x10*x11-x1*x14-x2*x17+x11*x20,
  -x4*x12+x10*x12-x5*x15+x11*x21,
  x4*x9-x3*x10-x4*x13+x10*x13-x5*x16+x11*x22,
  x5*x9-x3*x11-x4*x14+x10*x14-x5*x17+x11*x23,
  -x7*x12-x8*x15+x10*x15+x11*x24,
  x7*x9-x6*x10-x7*x13-x8*x16+x10*x16+x11*x25,
  x8*x9-x6*x11-x7*x14-x8*x17+x10*x17+x11*x26,
  -x9^2+x0*x12-x10*x12+x9*x13-x11*x15+x14*x18,
  -x9*x10+x1*x12-x11*x16+x14*x19,
  -x9*x11+x2*x12+x11*x13-x10*x14-x11*x17+x14*x20,
  x3*x12-x9*x12-x14*x15+x14*x21,
  x4*x12-x10*x12-x14*x16+x14*x22,
  x5*x12-x11*x12-x14*x17+x14*x23,
  x6*x12-x9*x15+x13*x15-x12*x16-x15*x17+x14*x24,
  x7*x12-x10*x15-x16*x17+x14*x25,
  x8*x12-x11*x15-x14*x16+x13*x17-x17^2+x14*x26,
  x0*x15+x9*x16-x9*x18+x17*x18-x12*x19-x15*x20,
  x1*x15+x10*x16-x10*x18-x13*x19+x17*x19-x16*x20,
  x2*x15+x11*x16-x11*x18-x14*x19,
  x3*x15+x12*x16-x9*x21+x17*x21-x12*x22-x15*x23,
  x4*x15+x13*x16-x10*x21-x13*x22+x17*x22-x16*x23,
  x5*x15+x14*x16-x11*x21-x14*x22,
  x6*x15+x15*x16-x9*x24+x17*x24-x12*x25-x15*x26,
  x7*x15+x16^2-x10*x24-x13*x25+x17*x25-x16*x26,
  x8*x15+x16*x17-x11*x24-x14*x25,
  x9*x19+x18*x20-x1*x21-x2*x24,
  x1*x18-x0*x19+x10*x19+x19*x20-x1*x22-x2*x25,
  x2*x18+x11*x19-x0*x20+x20^2-x1*x23-x2*x26,
  x12*x19-x4*x21+x20*x21-x5*x24,
  x4*x18-x3*x19+x13*x19-x4*x22+x20*x22-x5*x25,
  x5*x18+x14*x19-x3*x20-x4*x23+x20*x23-x5*x26,
  x15*x19-x7*x21-x8*x24+x20*x24,
  x7*x18-x6*x19+x16*x19-x7*x22-x8*x25+x20*x25,
  x8*x18+x17*x19-x6*x20-x7*x23-x8*x26+x20*x26,
  -x9*x18+x0*x21-x10*x21+x9*x22+x18*x23-x11*x24,
  -x9*x19+x1*x21+x19*x23-x11*x25,
  -x9*x20+x2*x21+x11*x22-x10*x23+x20*x23-x11*x26,
  -x12*x18+x3*x21-x13*x21+x12*x22+x21*x23-x14*x24,
  -x12*x19+x4*x21+x22*x23-x14*x25,
  -x12*x20+x5*x21+x14*x22-x13*x23+x23^2-x14*x26,
  -x15*x18+x6*x21-x16*x21+x15*x22-x17*x24+x23*x24,
  -x15*x19+x7*x21-x17*x25+x23*x25,
  -x15*x20+x8*x21+x17*x22-x16*x23-x17*x26+x23*x26,
  -x18^2-x19*x21+x0*x24-x20*x24+x9*x25+x18*x26,
  -x18*x19-x19*x22+x1*x24+x10*x25-x20*x25+x19*x26,
  -x18*x20-x19*x23+x2*x24+x11*x25,
  -x18*x21-x21*x22+x3*x24-x23*x24+x12*x25+x21*x26,
  -x19*x21-x22^2+x4*x24+x13*x25-x23*x25+x22*x26,
  -x20*x21-x22*x23+x5*x24+x14*x25,
  x6*x24-x18*x24+x15*x25-x21*x25,
  x7*x24-x19*x24+x16*x25-x22*x25,
  x8*x24-x20*x24+x17*x25-x23*x25}]],
  {x0,x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,
  x16,x17,x18,x19,x20,x21,x22,x23,x24,x25,x26},WorkingPrecision->32]
```

which in less than a minute responds with

```
{1.23221*^-15,
{x0->-0.250578,x1->-0.0381668,x2->0.00865906,x3->0.420365,
 x4->0.0032783,x5->0.0148975,x6->0.0305201,x7->0.0128096,
 x8->-0.172474,x9->0.420365,x10->0.0032783,x11->0.0148975,
 x12->-0.0488025,x13->0.393529,x14->-0.0379868,x15->-0.00345047,
 x16->-0.000137412,x17->0.392945,x18->0.0305201,x19->0.0128096,
 x20->-0.172474,x21->-0.00345047,x22->-0.000137412,x23->0.392945,
 x24->-0.00125624,x25->-0.0147376,x26->0.228844}}
```

You can adjust `WorkingPrecision`, `PrecisionGoal`, `AccuracyGoal` and other options to to try to get a better approximation if you need that.

Check this very carefully to make certain I have made no mistakes before you depend on it.

Comment: Interestingly, I get different results depending on the order of the equations and the value of `WorkingPrecision`.  In no case do I reproduce your result.  But, this does not surprise me.  Due to the symmetries of the equations, there probably are many solutions.

Comment: I have tried `Solve`, but at my age I probably would not live long enough to see the result.  Even `FindInstance` produces nothing in a reasonable time.  It also devours a lot of memory, perhaps trying to construct a Groebner Basis.

Comment: @ bbgodfrey, I also tried 'Solve' and  'FindInstance'.  The problem has solutions that are parameterized. For example, one can consider the case in which all the indices run from 0 to 1. In this case the system obtained (16 equations with 8 variables) has 12 solutions, some of them are parameterized.

Answer (score 0):

Here one of the possible solutions based on the so-called relinearization technique (see, i.e., https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/596.pdf). The main idea of the technique is to solve the system in terms of `y` s.t. `Subscript[x, i] Subscript[x, j] = Subscript[y, l]`

Here I define equations:

```
  Do[{i, j, k} = {0, 0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]]}; 
   Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 0, 2, 1}]
  Do[{i, j, k} = {0, IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], 
     IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]]}; 
   Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 3, 8, 1}]
  Do[{i, j, k} = {IntegerDigits[l, 3][[1]], IntegerDigits[l, 3][[2]], 
     IntegerDigits[l, 3][[3]]}; 
   Co[i, j, k] = Subscript[x, l], {l, 9, 26, 1}]
  Do[lam = j 3^3 + k 3^2 + n 3 + s; 
   Subscript[eq, lam] = 
          Sum[Co[j, k, m]*Co[m, n, s] - Co[k, n, m]*Co[j, m, s], {m, 0, 2, 
      1}], {j, 0, 2, 1}, {k, 0, 2, 1}, {n, 0, 2, 1}, {s, 0, 2, 1}]
```

Here I set the correspondence rule:

```
  sss = {}; l = 0;
  Do[Do[AppendTo[sss, Subscript[x, i] Subscript[x, j] -> y[l]]; 
     l = l + 1, {j, i, 26}], {i, 0, 26}];
```

Define the newequations in terms of y:

```
  Do[Subscript[eqq, k] = Subscript[eq, k] /. sss, {k, 0, 80}];
```

Here is the solution:

```
  Solve[And @@ Table[Subscript[eqq, k] == 0, {k, 0, 80}], 
  Table[y[k], k, 0, 377]]
```

We have 378 variables and 81 equations. Is it possible to express the solutions in terms of the old variables, `x`?